# Why does the git bisect command have a much wider range of commits than the one specified?

Tags: git, git-bisect

I did the following on a random git repository:

```
git bisect start
git bisect good HEAD~100
git bisect bad // Should just point to the current HEAD, right?
```

I would have expected a range of 100 commits to be tested by git, however what I got was 1000 commits (10x more). I am guessing there has to be a simple explanation for this, but I can't seem to find anything.

**Edit**: maybe I was not clear enough. I got 1000 commits in the range to be tested with git bisect. That would equate to roughly 9-10 commits to be tested.

What would the cause of this be?

Comment: what does `git rev-list HEAD~100..HEAD | wc -l` give you ? Maybe it's from branches and merges.

Comment: That gives me 3306. I am even more confused.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm afraid I don't know how exactly each commit reachable maps to which commits bisect considers, maybe somebody else who does know will chime in.

Comment: No worries, thanks for confusing me more though. :D

Comment: See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect-lk2009.html#_bisection_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very insightful question.

The commits are not all, necessarily, part of the same branch/trunk.  Bisect will follow the changesets as they are referenced, which may lead across multiple branches - in and out of merges.
This will yield a larger number of commits than what you expect based on the current branch.

If you compare the results from `git log -n100` with those from `git reflog` you will see this.